# Como combinar sucesiones en java

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto, espero me puedan ayudar.
El profesor nos ha dejado de tarea un programa que calcule la siguiente sucesión que tiene un patrón comportamental:
3, 5, 8, 7, 11, 9, 14, 11, 17...
Con la condición de que agregáramos un limite para la generación de la misma.

Me he venido arriba con el código de esta manera:

```
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1= 3, n2= 5, rep;
    System.out.println("Ingrese longuitud de la sucesión");
    rep= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i= 1; i <= rep; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(n1+ ", " + n2 + ", ");
        n1= n1+2;
        n2= n2+3;

    }
```

He generado dicha sucesión, pero tengo problemas al desplegar este por pantalla. No con la sucesión, si no con el numero de números en el que se extiende.

Ejemplo: 
**rep**(el numero de términos que quiero desplegar de sucesión)= 2;
Al desplegar la sucesión debería quedarme:
**5,3** y nada mas. Pero me sucede que en vez de desplegar lo anterior, me da **3, 5, 5, 8,** cuatro en vez de los 2 que especifique por teclado, osea, el doble de números que se especifican como limite.

Así que, ¿como puedo hacer que esto no suceda y que solo me despliegue por pantalla el limite que le establezca?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en cada iteración con el bucle estabas añadiendo dos términos a la sucesión, aquí tienes una implementación correcta:
Ahora solo se añade un termino a la sucesión, dependiendo de si el indice es par o impar.

```
public class Ejemplo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n1=3, n2=5;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Ingrese longuitud de la sucesión");
        int rep= sc.nextInt();
        for(int i= 0; i <= rep-1; i++) {
        if (i%2==0) {
             System.out.print(n1+ ", ");
             n1= n1+2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(n2 + ", ");
            n2= n2+3;
        }

        } 
    }
```

}

Comment: Genial! Tienes mucha razón! muchas gracias

Comment: Pero, haora me a surgido una nueva inquietud despues de mirar la solucion

Comment: Y si la sucesión hubiese sido de tres terminos?, y no de dos. Creo que en ese caso ya no se podria proceder de esa manera, como seria en ese caso?

Comment: ahí yo ya me haría un contador, que al ser mayor de tres se hiciera un reset a uno con un if por ejemplo.